# How do i make pinch zoom of the images in the same layout so that both the images work

Tags: android

I was new to the images concept i was unable to make the two images of different image views both images are not working only one pic which is place top is working fine but the other one is not able to move or drag Could any one help

```
package com.nst.touch;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.PointF;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.FloatMath;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {

    private static final String TAG = "Touch";

    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    Matrix savedMatrix = new Matrix();

    static final int NONE = 0;
    static final int DRAG = 1;
    static final int ZOOM = 2;
    int mode = NONE;

    PointF start = new PointF();
    PointF mid = new PointF();
    float oldDist = 1f;

    String fileName, time;

    ImageView view;
    ImageView view2;
    private int CAPTURE_IMAGE = 111;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pinchView);
        view.setOnTouchListener(this);

        view2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pinchPant);
        view2.setOnTouchListener(this);
    }

    public void takeShirt(View view) {
        Intent pic = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        time = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        fileName = "fab" + time + ".jpg";
        startActivityForResult(pic, CAPTURE_IMAGE);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE) {
            Bitmap pic = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

            view.setImageBitmap(pic);

            ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            pic.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ImageView view = (ImageView) v;

        dumpEvent(event);

        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

            savedMatrix.set(matrix);
            start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
            Log.d(TAG, "mode=DRAG");
            mode = DRAG;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
            mode = NONE;
            Log.d(TAG, "mode=NONE");
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if (mode == DRAG) {
                matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x, event.getY()
                        - start.y);
            } else if (mode == ZOOM) {
                float newDist = spacing(event);
                Log.d(TAG, "newDist =" + newDist);
                if (newDist > 10f) {
                    matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                    float scale = newDist / oldDist;
                    matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
                }
            }
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
            oldDist = spacing(event);
            Log.d(TAG, "oldDist=" + oldDist);
            if (oldDist > 10f) {
                savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                midpoint(mid, event);
                mode = ZOOM;
                Log.d(TAG, "mode = ZOOM");
            }
            break;
        }

        view.setImageMatrix(matrix);
        return true;
    }

    private void midpoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
        float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
        point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
    }

    private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
        float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
        return FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
    }

    private void dumpEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String names[] = { "DOWN", "UP", "MOVE", "CANCEL", "OUTSIDE",
                "POINTER_DOWN", "POINTER_UP", "7?", "8?", "9?" };
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int action = event.getAction();
        int actionCode = action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;
        sb.append("event ACTION_").append(names[actionCode]);
        if (actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN
                || actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP) {
            sb.append("(pid ").append(
                    action >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_ID_SHIFT);
            sb.append(")");
        }
        sb.append("[");
        for (int i = 0; i < event.getPointerCount(); i++) {
            sb.append("#").append(i);
            sb.append("(pid ").append(event.getPointerId(i));
            sb.append(")=").append((int) event.getX(i));
            sb.append(",").append((int) event.getY(i));
            if (i + 1 < event.getPointerCount()) {
                sb.append(";");
            }
            sb.append("]");
            Log.d(TAG, sb.toString());
        }
    }

}
```

I was not able to pinch the second view

Comment: can you place the code or elaborate what you are doing

Answer (score 0):

The way that you are handling and to my ans may differ, To zoom the view group items. you should create zoom for the parent ie) view group. go through this below mentioned link

[Zoom View Group](http://code.google.com/p/android-zoom-view/source/browse/src/pl/polidea/view/ZoomView.java?r=9ee0fc72b4783e23cdfeda6d46c6a948af855d78)

make this custom Frame layout as your parent for the views that you have. now you can zoom all the views present inside this view group.